# @font-face src:local() does not work on some fonts

Tags: html, css, browser, fonts, font-face

`@font-face src:local()` does not work on some fonts like [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode), but it works fine on other fonts like `Comic Sans MS`. Am i missing something?

Fira Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Custom';
        src: local('Fira Code');
      }

      .font {
        font-family: 'Fira Code';
      }

      .font-face {
        font-family: 'Custom';
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Fira Code: <span class="font">hijklmn</span></p>
    <p>Fira Code(@font-face): <span class="font-face">hijklmn</span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Chrome 91.0.4472.164:

[image: Chrome 91.0.4472.164 Fira Code]

Firefox 90.0:

[image: Firefox 90.0 Fira Code]

Comic Sans MS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Custom';
        src: local('Comic Sans MS');
      }

      .font {
        font-family: 'Comic Sans MS';
      }

      .font-face {
        font-family: 'Custom';
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Comic Sans MS: <span class="font">hijklmn</span></p>
    <p>Comic Sans MS(@font-face): <span class="font-face">hijklmn</span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Chrome 91.0.4472.164:

[image: Chrome 91.0.4472.164 Comic Sans MS]

Firefox 90.0:

[image: Firefox 90.0 Comic Sans MS]

More information:

- OS: Windows 10
- `Fira Code` is installed through `.ttf` files
- `Fira Code` can be used in any editor.

Comment: Do you have `Fira Code` font correctly installed on the system?

Comment: @ArRakin Please check the first HTML code and screenshots, I did installed `Fira Code`.

Comment: Which OS? How did you install that font on your system? Do other programs list it (e.g your text editor)?

Comment: I check about 50 fonts, and all of them works correctly, but Fira Code doesn't. It seems Fira Code has a problem on this situation.

Comment: @Kaiido Windows 10, `Fira Code` is installed through `.ttf` files, and `Fira Code` can be used in any editor.

Comment: This info would be better as an [edit] to your question. FWIW, installing the same .ttf on my macOs does work in both browsers, no Win at hand to test there.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to **Unblock** the font before installing in Windows 10.
If so, then this needs to be done on each .ttf file before installing.
[image: Unblock a font before installing]

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Fira';
  src: local('Fira Code'), local('FiraCode-Regular');
}

.font {
  font-family: 'Fira Code';
}

.font-face {
  font-family: 'Custom';
}
```

```html
<p><span class="font">Fira Code</span></p>
<span class="font-face">Fira Code(@font-face)</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `url(fontName.ttf)` instead of `local('Fira Code')` note there are no quotations in the url the code should look like this.

```html
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: Fira;
  src: url(FiraCode-Regular.ttf);
}
</style>
```

the `.ttf` file should be in the same directory as the html file.
you can download many fonts in `.ttf` format using [google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)